# Bluetooth USB smart dongle with HID support

Tags: bluetooth, usb, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Can somebody suggest a Bluetooth smart dongle which can convert the events triggered from any App into HID events (Keyboard strokes)?

Please help me out, we bought BLED112 but unfortunately that doesn't have the support of HID.

Comment: You got it working ? I'm also doing something similar. Have some doubts regarding the HID events over GATT ?

Comment: Yes we did, but with some Texas dongle we made it working over GATT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not purchased this, but Amazon has one [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CRY5K16) that seems to fit your description (despite a 3/5 star rating). Also you can check out [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009ZIILLI) dongle, that seems to cater more toward low energy. Good luck, and I hope you get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, we have even tabulated total 6 smart dongles...I can share the list here if anybody needs the same..Interacting with the technical teams of theirs to see if that meets our requirement or not.

Comment: We are planning to buy this Intelletto (Bluetooth Keyboard emulator) as their data sheet says it support "Converts bluetooth SPP profile character stream to USB keyboard strokes", do you have any idea about this?

Comment: If you're referring to [this](http://shop.intelletto.com/products/bk100), then I have no experience with it. I would look at their return policy just in case, though ;)

Comment: Hi All,

After a good amount of research we have bought some smart dongles and one of it has successfully worked for us.
And that is Intelletto Bluetooth Keyboard Emulator
Please see the site details and product details here.
http://www.intelletto.com/products/?id=3004
"Converts bluetooth SPP profile character stream to USB keyboard strokes."

We wrote a simple android app over Bluetooth SPP and receiver end the SPP characters are converted into HID key events automatically by the device.

Want to feed in this data to forum
Hope this helps somebody like me